# What does "beef on the rope" mean"

Tags: canadian-english

"The did have one good pro sailor, Ed Roach, for "beef on the rope" and shipkeeping and cooking."

Comment: "Beef on the rope" doesn't seem to be an idiom, but "on the ropes" is definitely an idiom.

Comment: try a google search!

Comment: There are a slew of related idioms in sailing where crew are commoditized humorously. Beef on the rope refers to hauling or grinding a winch, as opposed to rail meat that just sits there. [beef on a rope](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dfpNRkNI0mw). In general, this is a productive idiom that can be fitted to the situation. The stripped-out cabin of a racing boat is sometimes called the meat locker.

Comment: @lbf I did, and there were no relevant hits - zero - zip - nada.

Answer (score 1):

Sailing boats (and ships) require a lot of hauling on ropes for various reasons; somebody with enough muscle to apply force (and enough knowledge to apply the force properly) would be not so much valuable as invaluable.

Comment: Your answer would be better if it explained that "beef" is slang for "someone with lots of strength/muscle"

Comment: Not so much flammable as inflammable.